# How to run Gulp from a webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, build, gulp

I am trying to have Gulp as part of our build process after our code in pushed to our remote repository. My plan was to use a webhook that will fire after a commit is merged with origin.

How can I fire Gulp when the webhook is hit? I was thinking about just running node.js with a simple connect server, but from there how do I get gulp to run?

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect();

var myGulp = require('./gulpfile.js');

// respond to all requests
app.use(function(req, res){
  res.end('Hello from connect.\n');
})

//create node.js http server and listen on port
http.createServer(app).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a route for your webhook and call your gulp task from your `gulpfile` using [`gulp-chug`](https://github.com/robatron/gulp-chug)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var chug = require('gulp-chug');

app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  gulp.src('./gulpfile.js', { read: false})
    .pipe( chug( {
      tasks: ['default']  
    } ) );
});
```

Comment: Two issues I have with that: 1) When I run gulp.start() it says that is depreciated. Not sure how long that will be around. 2) When one of my tasks fails, it kills the whole process and node stops running.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be what I had originally intended, not sure where my head was when providing the answer. That should work. `start()` is provided by [`orchestrator`](https://github.com/orchestrator/orchestrator#3-run-the-tasks) which gulp is built on top of.

Comment: Any idea why when a Gulp task fails it would kill and shutdown my node process?

Comment: Can you post your gulp task code? Most likely you're doing some operation that is throwing an error and its not be caught.

Comment: Actually, when I try and use `.start()` I get the following error: #<Object> has no method 'start' -- code here: https://gist.github.com/jeremyhodges/3ed0af43800c0268f393